# MS Access SQL Combining 2 Pivot Results

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot

Continuing from the data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710313/ms-access-sql-transform-aggregate-manipluation-of-values-for-pivot), is there a way to add additional columns, for example, I have the following table:

```
Date       Quantity       Type       Cost     Date_Entered
01/02/15   23             Orange     452      10/01/15
01/02/15   10             Red        287      10/01/15
01/02/15   18             Yellow     315      10/01/15
02/02/15   15             Yellow     299      10/01/15
02/02/15   19             Red        320      10/01/15
.          .              .          .        .
.          .              .          .        .
```

Date is the calendar date of projected sales, Quantity is the number of sales, Type is the type of product (this may vary with the number of types), Cost is the total sales of the products, Date_Entered is the date that the data was put into the table and gives the forecast for the other columns. For each Date_Entered, there is the range of dates (say the whole of 2015). For each Date, there is every Type available.

The idea I have is to get to this kind of layout:

```
Date        Orange    Orange ($)  Red    Red ($)  Yellow  Yellow ($)
01/02/15    3         60           2      35       5       100
02/02/15    0         0           -2     -35      -1      -23
03/02/15    8         115         -1     -20       3       55
.           .         .            .       .       .       .
.           .         .            .       .       .       .
```

Where the values are the difference between the Quantity sold for a particular Date from one Date_Entered to another (e.g. change in projected sales over a week, month, quarter).

Now, in the link at the top of this post, the query has been established to get these values in two tables (one table with quantities and one with Cost). However, I am struggling to see how it can be done with MS Access SQL to combine them into one query for the result above. The TRANSFORM... PIVOT can only operate on one column and SELECT doesn't seem to be able to handle pivot results as a sub query. Is it easier to just output both tables into Excel and then just mix the columns together with VBA?

In addition, it would also be nice to have an average column for each type, but I think that is asking too much from SQL.

Thank you for any responses.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of your question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833836/ms-access-how-do-i-display-two-fields-from-separate-records-on-the-same-line-b]

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly state, a crosstab in Access unfortunately can only operate on one result column.

One way to achieve what you want in Accesss would be to create two "create table" queries each containing one of your crosstabs. Importantly, you need a unique primary key with each crosstab query (i.e. if this would be the date, then you must make sure, each crosstab has only one line per date).

Once you have both crosstab results as tables, you can join them using another query and your PK field.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, I would like to avoid creating tables. Is there a way to manipulate the data on the fly?

Comment: Another thing you could try is to join your crosstabs in another query but I'm not sure if this will work.

Comment: Have already tried this, but it's not valid. I think the idea with databases is to the have the data ready for extraction rather than changing most of it during export. I'll work round this with either database side with more tables or client side manipulation with more than one query.